# Database structure for assigning an item to a user or group, but not both

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I can't figure out how to structure a database to model what I'm trying to do.

Let's say as an example, I have the following tables `User` and `Group` they both have the following columns `Id` and `Name`

Now, I have an object called `Item`. An `Item` can be assigned to a `User` or a `Group`, but not both at once. It's also valid to have an `Item` that's assigned to no `User` nor `Group`. Is there a way to lay this out in a database that makes sense? Will I be forced to use custom constraints on a record insert that checks to see if the logic (where an item can't be assigned to both a `User` and `Group` simultaneously) is valid?

I feel like there's absolutely no way I've been the first person to run into this problem, but I'm not seeing similar questions. Thanks.

For context, I'm just trying to design this so I can use a database model that makes sense to me that I'll end up creating Code-First in Entity Framework in C#. I didn't tag it with that because it doesn't seem relevant enough to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach that would enforce the constraints you describe at the database level.

Implement your `Item` table like so:

```
create table [dbo].[Item] (
    pkid int identity primary key,
    AssignedTo_UserId int null,
    AssignedTo_GroupID int null,
    constraint fk_User foreign key (AssignedTo_UserId) references [dbo].[User] (Id),
    constraint fk_Group foreign key (AssignedTo_GroupID) references [dbo].[Group] (Id),
    constraint user_xor_group check (not (AssignedTo_UserId is not null and AssignedTo_GroupID is not null))
);
```

You'll have two assignment fields, one for `User` and one for `Group`.  The foreign key constraints ensure that an `Item` can't be assigned to a non-existent `User` or `Group`, and the check constraint ensures that only one of either `AssignedTo_UserId` or `AssignedTo_GroupID` ever has a non-null value (i.e. your item is only assigned to a single user or group at a time, never to both).

However, that table design looks funny to me; it might be a good fit for your particular use cases (whatever those may be), but it seems unlikely.

If you were picturing something like two mutually exclusive foreign key constraints on the same column, i.e. table `Item` has a single `AssignedTo` column that must match an `Id` in either `Group` or `User`, I don't know of any way to do that.  (you can have two constraints on the *same* column referencing *different* tables, but they'd always be applied, e.g. `AssignedTo` would have to match both `Group` *and* `User`, and that's not what you've asked for).

If your `User` and `Group` tables are as similar as they look (i.e. only have Name and Id columns) then [@Brian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31550730/4154) is almost surely the way to go.  If they have a lot of different columns, then there might be an argument for sub-classing in your db design, and you'd want to work through the trade-offs of your designs and pick whichever best fits your requirements.

Comment: This is one of the designs that I've come up with and I can't think of anything else that will fit what it is I need to do and with the way my users and roles are currently set up (as separate tables - dictated by the default .NET Identity Framework) I might have to go with this one. I'll leave this open for a while and check back to see if there are any more hits, but I wanted to make sure that I wasn't overlooking something really simple here... Thanks so much for your input.

Comment: I'm probably going to go with this and supplement it with code-behind logic as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose one way to handle it would be to make users and groups all one entity but defined with a flag attribute to tell if it's a user or a group.  So for example create a table called `Credentials` and you could add a flag called `Type` that would be set to either a value that indicates it is a user or a group.  This way you can just have one `CredentialID` field in your `Item` table and just validate that it matches a record in the `Credentials` table.  There may be reasons why you might not want to do it that way, but it is an option to consider.

If your `Group` and `User` tables are not simple, then here is another way to look at it that might be a better solution.  You could think about your `Group` table as your `Credential` table.  Every record in the `Item` table can only link to one `Group`.  Every user has a group where it is the only member.  You could mark this record in the `Group` table with a flag if necessary so that your user interfaces don't alter it and also so they can know if it's really a group or if it's simply a single user if necessary.  This not only eliminates the conditional logic in your constraint, but also all over your application.  Items can only link to a group, and a group links to it's user/users.

Comment: That is certainly an option. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I added a second paragraph to build on the original idea.